# Expanding on a classic

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, no-computers, three-dimensional

**F**rom the simple caesar to the see**m**ingly uncrackable elliptic curve, there are countless ways to obscure **-** and even hide - a sensi**t**ive message. Cryptograp**h**y is quite **i**nte**r**es**t**ing in this wa**y**. I **f**ind the simpler ones - which are solvable thr**ou**gh pen and pape**r** **-** to be **f**un little puzzles. The only problem is, once you know how to s**o**lve a particular type, it becomes less interesting to solve anothe**r** of the same. **T**here are a handful of popular ciphers which get published ever**y**where **-** beaten to death. **T**he unique, custom one offs are much harder to come by. So, belo**w** is my contributi**o**n.

This cipher **s**yst**e**m stands atop the shoulders of another **v**ersion. It takes a classic to the next dimension, and whil**e** I could simply tell you the steps of encryptio**n** are X,Y,Z in that order **-** I find it more satisfying **t**o deduce the method myself than to follo**w** pr**o**cedure.

You will, of course, need somewhere to start. So hopefully this will assist you.
Sxz pxkd, f- vj-enr, fhjl iyshjklcg ay mttuk. Oq hkbhcix-m rrui rijz ybtubr sxz.

```
a b c      |  M A E       B G J       N H I
d e f      |  B F D       I A D       L J K
g h i      |  H C J       - L C       M G C
  j k l    |    L G I       E K M       B D -
  m n o    |    N K -       N H F       E F A
  p q r    |    O P Q       V Y Q       S Q Z
    s t u  |      Y W U       S T X       T V W
    v w x  |      S Z V       W P Z       U P Y
    y z -  |      X T R       O R U       O R X
```

To solve this puzzle, you must decrypt this: `XZIUXCFGIJ-QTCA`
And give an explanation on the encryption/decryption scheme of the cipher.

Happy cracking!

hint 1:

> It may help to visualize these cubes like so:
>  [image: 3D_visualization]

hint 2:

> This cipher variation is based off of Félix Delastelle's four-square cipher

hint 3:

> While the four-square cipher uses four 5x5 squares, if it is regular (the plaintext squares are `a-z` in order, skipping `j`, top left to bottom right) then all that is *needed* is 3 squares. The variation I created is minified using this same concept.

hint 4:

> Lets do some analysis on the four-square cipher. This encryption scheme is typically represented visually, but it can also be expressed using the coordinates X and Y. For example, take the following four-square cipher.
>  [image]
>  If we were to encrypt `cipher` we would first split the plaintext into the pairs `ci|ph|er`, which could then be expressed as the coordinates (`X,Y`) `3,1 4,2 | 5,3 3,2 | 5,1 2,4`. The process of encryption/decryption by visually following the rows and columns of a typical four-square cipher is the exact same as simply swapping the X coordinates. Plaintext `3,1 4,2` becomes the ciphertext `4,1 3,2`. The full ciphertext is therefore `HROWRZ`.
>  Breaking down the four-square cipher like this makes it much easier to extend the scheme to use 3 coordinates: X,Y,Z. However, with 3 coordinates you can't just swap. You'll have to use some form of rotation ;)

hint 5:

> The Four-Square cipher is a digraphic cipher, because it encodes a message using *pairs* of letters. The encryption/decryption scheme I have come up with is a ***tri**graphic cipher*

Solution spoiler:

> Originally, I named this cipher the `six-square cipher` due to the use of 6 full blocks for the key, however, I overlooked the fact that these blocks are not squares like in the four-square cipher, but instead cubes due to the extra dimension. Therefore this cipher should instead be named the `six-cube cipher`. Cisko solved this when the ciphertext to decrypt was `XZIIORIOIACKHHGRQX` aka the original name. His answer is correct. I have updated the question to contain the proper (encrypted) name though, because it will nag me if I don't.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! We usually don't encourage posting this many hints to start. Puzzles are supposed to be solvable without any hints. If you feel the hints are needed, just put them as part of the puzzle itself.

Comment: Ah, whoops. I will keep that in mind and edit hints into the question in the future. The cipher is certainly solvable without the hints, and in fact I did provide a few subtle hints in the preface text. The numbered hints at the bottom are just there to help you get on track with the right thought process for solving, if you are lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**XZIIORIOIACKHHGRQX = SIX-SQUARECIPHER--**
Using the same way you figured out to solve the 4 squares, where you switched the "X" in the coordinates of each original letter of the pair (digraphic), but as you stated, it can't be just "switched" in a tridimensional coordinate system (x,y,z), so they must be "rotated", taking the sample text you stated, where SXZ becomes YOU, I got the right rotation number, which is 0 for the X, 1 for the Y and 2 for the Z.
Also, using the bold letter of your text I got FM-THIRTYFOUR-FORTY-TWO-SEVEN-TWO, which stands for the Basic Cryptanalysis document of the department of army, Basic Cryptoanalisis *FM 34-40-2, on chapter 7-2 which is the solution of regular 4 squares (https://fas.org/irp/doddir/army/fm34-40-2/ch7.pdf).
Nicely done!

[image]

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this is correct (I have a feeling it is), this is a fantastic answer for a new contributor! Well done!

Comment: Well done! I like the way you set up that spreadsheet to lay out the workings of the cipher. Answer is correct and accepted